# Need to change background color on scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In our website, I am trying to change the background-color of the header on scroll, but I didn't get any id or class specific to that scroll action.

Please find below URL:
http://indemortgage.staging.wpengine.com/

Please revert me with solution

Already tried below code:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".header").addClass("active");
        } else {
            //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
           $(".header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

I want relevant id or class to change background color on scroll.

Comment: your code is wrong.. pls remove  (dot ) header

Comment: you check that url... header is not class, is tat tag.. so he should remove dot(header) in jquery and its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your sharable Link and observed that already on the page scroll one class is added to the header and on scroll top, it removes also. "header--not-sticked" this class is added to your header while it is not scrolled and "header--is-sticked" this class is added to your header on-page is scroll. So you can easily apply your CSS using both classes, Hope so this will help you.

```
Also, you have used the wrong class name to add and remove class, you need to remove "." from the header and make it an element because on your website there is no "header" class to your header element. Try the below code


$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("header").addClass("active");
        } else {
            //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
           $("header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly, I am using the given classes "header--not-sticked" for non-sticky and "header--is-sticked" for sticky header and it's working

Comment: Hello Gopal, Sound good that it solves your issue, can you please accept my answer and vote me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more thing, I have changed background color by using "header--not-sticked" class. But now I want to change menu color on scroll the window. because Menu color class is different and which will apply for both sticky and non-sticky menu classes. So I want menus color are white without scroll and those should be black after scrolled.

Comment: Hello @Gopal You can give the background colors using the same class, from your sharable site. You can use  "header--not-sticked kl-top-header" class for not scrolled and give the color which you want

Answer (score 1):

In your site header is not class. so can you remove (dot) and add header in jquery
**jquery**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("header").addClass("active");
        } else {
            //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
           $("header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

**css**

```
header.active{
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code that you all are adding the class to header when 150 is scrolled. Then go to css and update `active` add property to.Check it, Running Example Below:

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
            $(".header").addClass("active");
        } else {
            //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
           $(".header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.header{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.active{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if header is your class :

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".header").css("background-color", "red");
        } else {
            $(".header").css("background-color", "blue");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and found a little mistake in your code, you choose the wrong selector ".header" instead you have to use "#header" because there is no header class in the header tag.

This code is working fine :

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        jQuery("#header").addClass("active");
    } else {
        //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
       jQuery("#header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Add css :

```
header.active{ background-color:red;}
```